# Setting up Google Play Services on Eclipse

Tags: android, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

I'm getting an error when trying to import google play services :
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It said that you made a change in the library.  Try to re-download the Google Play services library.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help..

Comment: What is the source you downloaded from?

Comment: ok I think I got it working somehow..Thank you Ido